# Crystal Reports - How to take UTC Date and show it as localtime?

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports

I have a report that is showing some dates and times that are stored in the database in a UTC format, but the users are on UTC-5 AND UTC-4. The reports are running locally, is there a function to convert a UTC date to Localtime, as set on the machine running the report?

e.g. =TolocalTime(UTCDATETIME) ?

I can see from searching that there is a static offset you can apply to a date field, which would be fine, if i was only fielding to users in one area.

is this possible?

There is a "CurrentDateTime" function that does correctly pull the current local time, but i cannot see any way to use this to help

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on an old version of Crystal, you can use this function:
***ShiftDateTime (inputDateTime, inputTimeZone, newTimeZone)***

If your version of Crystal doesn't have that function, you can use a Crystal Reports UFL (User Function Library) that provides a function for converting UTC time to Local time. Ken Hamady maintains a list of 3rd-party UFLs [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl).
At least one of them provides such a function.

Comment: Thanks, thats just a static single timezone still isnt it? Convert utc to a single one, no way to say 'local' in the last param?

Comment: You need to use the built in function PrintTimeZone to select the local time zone. try this: ShiftDateTime (YourUTCTimeField, "UTC,0", PrintTimeZone)

Answer (score 0):

See the online help for that function in Crystal.

**An empty string indicates the local time zone from the OS settings.**